# Selenium IDE HTML Enriquecido

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE, but when i tried with command type over a enrich html do not work. Anybody have any idea what I can to do?

Comment: Please define **DO NOT WORK** and please read through [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @Saifur, I tried command: Type Target: css=iframe[title*='Editor de texto enriquecido, instrucciones'] Value: Prueba and don't write anything

Comment: @Karina_Serrano I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish there. But, looks like you are trying to type on a `tag` which does not accept typing which in your case is `iframe`

Comment: @Karina_Serrano Provide detail `html` and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @Saifur HMTL from selenius is <tr>
 <td>sendKeys</td>
 <td>css=iframe[title*='Editor de texto enriquecido, instrucciones']</td>
 <td>Ins</td>
</tr>

Comment: @Saifur, code is: <iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Editor de texto enriquecido, instrucciones" aria-describedby="cke_103" tabindex="12" allowtransparency="true">

Comment: @Saifur it's work  Comand: Click Target: 'button HTML of iframe' and Command: sendKeys Target: xpath=//*[contains (@title, 'Editor de texto enriquecido, instrucciones')] Value: Escribe algo.